# NUnit's CollectionAssert return false for similar lists of custom class

Tags: c#, nunit, assert, equality

Here is my class:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FaminlyName { get; set; }
    public int Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have two similar list:

```cs
List<MyClass> list1 = new List<MyClass>()
{
    new MyClass() {FaminlyName = "Smith", Name = "Arya", Phone = 0123},
    new MyClass() {FaminlyName = "Jahani", Name = "Shad", Phone = 0123}
};
List<MyClass> list2 = new List<MyClass>()
{
    new MyClass() {FaminlyName = "Smith", Name = "Arya", Phone = 0123},
    new MyClass() {FaminlyName = "Jahani", Name = "Shad", Phone = 0123}
};
```

The problem is that NUnit CollectionAssert return false always.

```cs
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(list1,list2);
```

Am I missing something about CollectionAssert test

Comment: It checks references for equality not elements inside

Comment: @dotctor it does check the elements in the list, it's called `CollectionAssert.AreEqual()`, not `Assert.AreEqual()`. Anyway, of the collection elements, it does compare reference equality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `AreEqual` checks for equality of the objects. Since you did not override the `Equals` method, it will return `false` in case the *references* are not equal.

You can solve this by overriding the `Equals` method of your `MyClass`:

```
public class MyClass {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FaminlyName { get; set; }
    public int Phone { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals (object obj) {
         MyClass mobj = obj as MyClass;
         return mobj != null && Object.Equals(this.Name,mobj.Name) && Object.Equals(this.FaminlyName,mobj.FaminlyName) && Object.Equals(this.Phone,mobj.Phone);
    }

}
```

You furthermore better override the `GetHashCode` method as well:

```
public class MyClass {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FaminlyName { get; set; }
    public int Phone { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals (object obj) {
         MyClass mobj = obj as MyClass;
         return mobj != null && Object.Equals(this.Name,mobj.Name) && Object.Equals(this.FaminlyName,mobj.FaminlyName) && Object.Equals(this.Phone,mobj.Phone);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode () {
        int hc = 0x00;
        hc ^= (this.Name != null) ? this.Name.GetHashCode() : 0;
        hc ^= (this.FaminlyName != null) ? this.FaminlyName.GetHashCode() : 0;
        hc ^= this.Phone.GetHashCode();
        return hc;
    }

}
```

Comment: then in the second solution, we can compare the HashCode of the lists by Assert.AreEqual() , is it right?

Comment: Mind that two lists are not equal because all the elements are equal. So `CollectionAssert.AreEqual` will succeed, but `Assert.AreEqual` will still fail. A hashcode is simply used for `HashSet<T>` and `Dictionary<TK,TV>` objects. But the hashcode must be consistent with the equality operation.