# Compare two Lists using IComparer

Tags: c#, list

I have 2 lists of type `Animal` (a class with the properties `Breed` and `Name`) and I need to compare them in Unit tests using `CollectionAssert`

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    List<Animal> list1 = new List<Animal> ()
    {
       new Animal("Dog", "Charlie"),
       new Animal("Cat", "Mittens"),
       new Animal("Cow", "Bacon"),
    };

    List<Animal> list2 = new List<Animal> ()
    {
       new Animal("Dog", "Charlie"),
       new Animal("Cat", "Mittens"),
       new Animal("Cow", "Bacon"),
    };

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(list1,list2);
}
```

The test fails with elements at index 0 do not match

I implemented a class `CustomCompare` that implements `IComparer`

```
public class CustomCompare : IComparer<Animal>
{
    public int Compare(Animal a, Animal b)
    {
        return String.Compare(a.Name,b.Name);
    }
}
```

Now when I try to add the comparer as a parameter to `CollectionAssert.AreEqual` method is still not working

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(list1,list2, "true", new CustomComparer())
```

The test still fails with the same message error.

Comment: Yo collection contains different objects, reference types are compared by reference equality, not by value. As for the custom comparer, you've used invalid overload of `AreEqual` method and incorrect implementation of `IComparer`, it should be non generic one

Comment: you want to add a customeComparer to compare names, so i suggest to use just instead:``CollectionAssert.AreEqual(list1.Select(x=>x.Name),list2.Select(x=>x.Name));``

Comment: The exact duplicate, using `Equals` will solve the question [NUnit's CollectionAssert return false for similar lists of custom class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382277/nunits-collectionassert-return-false-for-similar-lists-of-custom-class)

Comment: If the approach suggested in the duplicate (overriding Equals and GetHashCode in your Animal class) fits better, please let me know and I can remove the answer.

Comment: @Sajid Your approach seems the easiest, but if someone else needs it, you also have to add .ToList() because CollectionAssert.AreEqual() needs ICollection while the Select method will return an IEnumerable<string>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override Equals or by implementing the non-generic base interface:

```
public class CustomCompare : IComparer<Animal>, IComparer
{
    public int Compare(Animal a, Animal b)
    {
        return String.Compare(a.Name, b.Name);
    }

    int IComparer.Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        return Compare((Animal)x, (Animal)y);
    }
}
```

You can pass this like:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(list1, list2, new CustomCompare());
```

Or; with having a custom message:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(list1, list2, new CustomCompare(), "true");
```